Join User and LoginHistory results into a single table list or map
The objects User and LoginHistory have no relation although both have a property for user id. I want to join / merge the result of two queries

all active users: SharingCriteria__c, Project__c, Id, Name, Username
all logins of the last 4 quartres: loginCount, minLoginTime, maxLoginTime

into a single table.



Id
Sharing
Proj
Name
LoginCount
MinLoginTime
MaxLoginTime




123
A
Bar
Tom Doe
4
2023/12
2024/06


589
K
Foo
Neo
54
2024/02
2024/08



These queries both work
SELECT UserId, COUNT(Id) loginCount, 
           MIN(LoginTime) minLoginTime, MAX(LoginTime) maxLoginTime
FROM LoginHistory
WHERE LoginTime = LAST_N_QUARTERS:4
GROUP BY UserId

-- users
SELECT SharingCriteria__c, Project__c, Id, Name, Username, IsActive
FROM User
WHERE IsActive = true

But since Salesforce doe not support nested queries / subqueries like SELECT Id, Username FROM User WHERE Id in (SELECT UserId FROM LoginHistory WHERE ...) and based on this similar question i assume i have to use an apex  script to merge the two results like this
Set<String> userIds = new Set<String>();
for (AggregateResult record : [SELECT UserId FROM LoginHistory
    WHERE LoginTime = LAST_N_QUARTERS:4 
    GROUP BY UserId]) {
    userIds.add((String)record.get('UserId'));
}

List<User> userList = [SELECT SharingCriteria__c, Project__c, 
                       Id,Name, Username 
                       FROM User WHERE Id in :userIds];

// Debug statement to display the results
for (User obj : userList) {
     System.debug('Record: ' + JSON.serialize(obj));
}

The script above seems to work but it also returns properties i do not need like

url,
CurrencyIsoCode

example
[12]|DEBUG|Record: 
{"attributes":
   {"type":"User","url":"/.../sobjects/User/..."},
   "SharingCriteria__c":"N", "Project__c":"foobar",
   "Id":"0059Z0..","Name":"Tom Doe", "Username":"tom@doe.com",
   "CurrencyIsoCode":"Bar"
}

What is missing?
The result i want must include the attributes LoginCount, Max + Min LoginTime. But trying to merge two maps seems to be difficult / impossible.
Here is javascript code that demonstrates what i want to achieve.
const userArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alice' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bob' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Charlie' }
];

const loginHistoryArray = [
    { id: 1, age: 25 },
    { id: 2, age: 30 },
    { id: 4, age: 40 }
];

const mergedArray = userArray.map(itemA => {
    const itemB = loginHistoryArray.find(itemB => itemB.id === itemA.id);
    return itemB ? { ...itemA, ...itemB } : itemA;
});

console.log(mergedArray);

The above javascript code creates this array

How can this achieved in an apex script?

The attributes property is part of SObject JSON serialization that helps with identifying the record, while the CurrencyIsoCode suggests your org has multi-currency enabled.
